# How Hisotgram Equalizaion is Recursively Performed in RSIHE and RSWHE?

Tags: image-processing

I am working in Digital Image Enhancement filed. recently i have studied Histogram Equalization and it different variations such as AHE, CLAHE, BBHE, DSIHE, RMSHE and RSIHE. In RSIHE and RMSHE, histogram of input image is segmented into two or more sub-histograms recursively and then HE process is applied in each sub-histogram independently. Suppose for recursion level r=2 where the histogram is segmented into 4 sub-histograms, would the HE process be applied six time????

[image: Histogram Segmentation by RMSHE]

In the above case the histogram is segmented into four sub-histograms. [0 h1] [h1 h2] [h2 h3] [h3 L-1] (L-1 is MAX gray level of image).

Now my question is that

how many times HE process will be applied

1. Six Times [0 h2] [h2 L-1] [0 h1] [h1 h2] [h2 h3] [h3 L-1]
2. Four Times [0 h1] [h1 h2] [h2 h3] [h3 L-1]

Thank You

Comment: The question doesn't seem clear enough. Could you please provide a link to the code or to the paper/article you are referring to for this algorithm? Otherwise we don't know what approach you are using exactly.

Comment: you can refer about the RMSHE from [link](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=01261233) and about RSIHE from [link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167865507000578). I only want to know that how these algorithms finally equalize the image.

Comment: The first link doesn't work, and I can't download the paper off the second without paying for it. Is it possible for you to upload the papers somewhere and copy in a link, or at least summarise the algorithms?

Comment: first link is this [link1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vuc6ff5vqbvpu69/RMSHE.pdf) and second one is this [link2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1k3blfo95ji0azi/RSIHE.pdf), now you can download it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just went through both papers, and histogram equalisation is definitely applied 4 times in both cases, not 6 times. The "windows" for equalisation don't overlap at all. So option (2) it is.